# Why does amarok emit gobs and gobs of "QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Cannot make invalid context current"?

Tags: linux-mint, logs, qt, devuan, amarok

When I start amarok on my Linux Mint 18.2 (edit: and on my Devuan ASCII), I get a huge flow of

```
QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Cannot make invalid context current
```

on stderr. Why could that be? Can I avoid it somehow without shutting amarok down?

Note: I have both on-board Intel graphics (which I actually use for my X server) and an nVIDIA GTX 650 card (which I use for compute work).

Comment: Have you considered asking Amarok's developers?

Comment: @SatōKatsura: Actually no, since I assumed it's a distribution-related problem, but maybe that's not such a bad idea. Also, I was hoping it was an issue other people have encountered as users/sysadmins and could answer here.

Comment: Qt applications on the loose have this habit of spewing debug information that is only ever meaningful to the authors.  The same authors are also the ones who can make said applications shut up, by re-compiling them with the appropriate options.  In principle distribution maintainers can do the same, but they may or may not be aware of the best ways to do it.  But either way there isn't much you can do about it as an end user.

Comment: @SatōKatsura: But maybe I can avoid the "context" being "invalid"...

Comment: In order to avoid it you'd have to understand first what said context is, and why it's invalid.  Do you?  Do you know anybody who does?  Do you know anybody who might be qualified to tell you?

Comment: @SatōKatsura: No, no, and no, which is why I'm asking here...

Comment: The first anniversary of your post just happened a few days ago.  Given the number of responses you received so far, perhaps it's time to reconsider my first comment above?  To put it in simpler words: your question is too specific for a general forum, only Amarok's developers _might_ have enough of a clue to answer it.

Comment: @SatōKatsura: Indeed, see my new answer.

Comment: Useful application, good support, free; pick two.  It happens.

Comment: @SatōKatsura: The thing is, I don't mind being told "your case is esoteric, we won't work on it right now". It's just that I'm basically waived off.

Comment: I didn't read the developers' answer as waving you off.  They (politely) asked you to try the latest version and report back if the problem persists.  That's reasonable: no free project these days has enough resources to support __all__ historic releases, the vast majority of them can only afford to go back one or two releases.  And no, just because the problem looks like it isn't specific to a version, it doesn't mean it really is so under the hood.  From the point of view of a developer, even looking at code that is no longer supported is a waste of time.  Don't read into it more than it is.

Comment: @SatōKatsura: If they'd said "we did work on that code between 2.8.0 and 2.9.0, try that" - then fine. If that's not the case, then a bug with 2.8.0 is typically a bug with 2.9.0. As a developer myself, I know I must accept people reporting bugs with the common release versions, not with the latest , rather than expect them to build and install a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I've filed a bug about this issue with the Amarok developers:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=399037

It was promptly closed since they won't be bothered to support their version installed on millions of boxes with distributions based on Debian Stable or Ubuntu Xenial or Trusty. So, that was a lot of help...

I'm trying to build their latest version, will update this answer if I have any success on that front.